# Adjust TOPCOUNT to be time aware

Tags: mdx

Got the following script but it seems to pull back the top 15 customers by NumDeals that they have made over all time - rather than by the last 7 days.

How do I adjust the set to reflect this requirement?

```
WITH 
    SET [Set_7Days] as
        TAIL ([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], 7)
    SET [Set_Top15Customers] as
         {
          TOPCOUNT (
           [CustomerDim].[CustomerDim].[CustomerLevel].members,
           15,
            ( 
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].currentmember, 
            [Measures].[NumDeals] 
            )
          )
         }
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY
        [Set_7Days]
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
        [Set_Top15Customers]
    ON ROWS
FROM [ourCube]
WHERE ( 
    [Measures].[NumDeals] 
    )
```

---

**EDIT**

Using mmarie help I've got the following: wanted to keep things in a custom set so that I can add it to a `PIVOT` connected to a `CUBE` in `EXCEL`:

```
WITH 
    SET  as
        TAIL ([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], 7)
    SET [Set_Top15Customers] as
         {
          TOPCOUNT (
           [CustomerDim].[CustomerDim].[CustomerLevel].members,
           15,
           Sum(
                   [Set_7Days], //TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], 7), 
                   [Measures].[NumDeals]
                   )
          )
         }
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY
        [Set_7Days]
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
        [Set_Top15Customers]
    ON ROWS
FROM [ourCube]
WHERE ( 
    [Measures].[NumDeals] 
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the date filter into your top count. There are probably a few ways to do this.  This one works, but you might have to check performance to see if it is acceptable.

Try this:

```
with
member [measures].[Num Deals last 7 days] as  
Sum(Head([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], 7), [Measures].[NumDeals])

select 
NON Empty {TAIL ([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], 7)[measures].[Num Deals Last 7 days]} on 0,
NON Empty {topcount( {[CustomerDim].[CustomerDim].[CustomerLevel].members}, 5, measures.[Num Deals last 7 days])} on 1
FROM [ourCube]
WHERE ( [Measures].[NumDeals] )
```

Comment: +1 MDX lady - ace - works fine. Only change I've made is moved your numeric expression into my set (I'll amend OP so you can see what I mean). Reason I want it all in the set is that OLAP into an Excel PIVOT seems to only allow custom sets....not sure how to create custom members within that environment

Comment: ....actually when I do that it seems I can just reuse the 7 day set I created just to shorten the code a bit....lets see if xl now complains.